# Metropolis theme: Skip one section page but keep the others

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I have a metropolis presentation where I want to have section intro frames for every section but the first one (its common in my field to jump right into the introduction). I know I can turn off section slides with:

```
\metroset{sectionpage=none}
```

but I don't know how to turn them on again.

```
\metroset{sectionpage=simple}
```

afterwards doesn't do it.

Here is a **minimal example** with my attempt commented out:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

%\metroset{sectionpage=none}
\section{This should not have an intro frame}
%\metroset{sectionpage=simple}

\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}

\section{I want this one to have an intro frame}

\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

if you uncomment, all intro slides are lost.

edit: the documentation is [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/metropolis/doc/metropolistheme.pdf) and the part I am using is on page 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\metroset{sectionpage=none}` (or `\molochset{sectionpage=none}` if you use the more modern fork `moloch` instead of the `metropolis` theme) within a group around the one section which should not have a section page:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

{
\molochset{sectionpage=none}
\section*{This should not have an intro frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}

\section{I want this one to have an intro frame}

\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: that is awesome and probably useful in many other settings :-D At some point, I should learn a bit more about Latex... This learning by doing coding has its limits...

Comment: @PeterPan You could just learn on the fly with your user name :)

Comment: Just always be waiting for me...